# Ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is the simplest form of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+2X)$ ?

I tried to use the first isomorphism theorem, but I have problems if finding a proper map $\phi$ such that $\ker\phi=(X^2+2X)$.

Comment: What do ou mean by simplest form ? You can say that it is $\mathbb Z[a]$ such that $a^2+2a=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $\phi:\Bbb Z[X]\to\Bbb Z^2\;, P\mapsto (P(0),P(-2))$

Comment: Less trivially, you need to characterize the image.